# Get hidden input value and view in popovers JavaScript

Tags: javascript, input, hidden, popover

Did read data from   hidden and view in a modal window - it worked. Changed from modal to popovers - stopped working. I do not know how to correct. Help please, tried a lot of things. [http://jsfiddle.net/popovers](http://jsfiddle.net/Lkumqbym/1/)

```
<div id="myPopoverContent">
    .....
    <span id="ip_view">no ip</span>
</div>

<a tabindex='0' class='btn  btn-danger' role='button' id='pop'  data-toggle='popover' data-trigger='focus'>                  
    Check
    <input id='ip_id' type='hidden' value='94.45.43.42'> 
</a>

<a tabindex='0' class='btn  btn-danger' role='button' id='pop'  data-toggle='popover' data-trigger='focus'>                  
    Check
    <input id='ip_id' type='hidden' value='83.218.164.204'> 
</a>            

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
       $('[data-toggle=popover]').popover({
        content: $('#myPopoverContent').html(),
        placement: 'bottom',
        html: true
    }).click(function() {
    var ip = this.firstElementChild.value;  
    document.getElementById('ip_view').innerHTML = ip; 
        $(this).popover('show');
    });
});

</script>
```

I do not understand why is not working. In modal or alert - work [http://jsfiddle.net/modal](http://jsfiddle.net/nsy04nfr/1/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The content of the popup is set on create, so even though you update the value inside `myPopoverContent`, the content was set to the original html of the div when the document was ready (which is `<span id="ip_view">no ip</span>`). Here's a better and cleaner way of getting the content when the popup is opened.

**Code**

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lkumqbym/3/)

```
$('[data-toggle=popover]').popover({
    content: function(){return $(this).children("#ip_id").val();},
    placement: 'bottom'
});
```

Edit: Had the wrong fiddle link

Comment: Thank you, but I need to display my div block in this popover. And ip. How can to display and custom div, and get ip?

Comment: You could try [this](http://jsfiddle.net/Lkumqbym/4/) or see the template section [here](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#popovers-options)

Comment: html tags display like a text

Comment: That was my mistake, sorry. You'll need to use the `template` option. See my simple example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Lkumqbym/7/)

Comment: You helped me a lot. Could you tell me more how to enter  this IP in link in a iframe? Please. My attempts to do so have been unsuccessful. http://jsfiddle.net/Lkumqbym/8/  instead 94.45.43.42 must be ip from input.